# datepart function not considering updated date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datepart

The `datepart` function, when applied with the parameter `week`, was showing results of updated rows as well, even though the date is not in the range of the given week:

```
select INSTALLATION_DATE 
from {MyTABLE} 
where datepart(WEEK, INSTALLATION_DATE) = 24
```

Results:

```
2022-06-05 10:11:48.0000000
2022-06-05 06:11:48.0000000
2021-06-08 10:29:41.0000000
2021-06-08 10:36:53.0000000
2021-06-08 10:37:52.0000000
2021-06-08 10:39:24.0000000
2021-06-08 10:40:03.0000000
2021-06-07 10:43:11.0000000
2021-06-09 10:43:54.0000000
```

The first two rows have been updated with a future date, but still are shown as in week 24 (`2021-06-06` to `2021-06-12`)

Comment: They are showing because they belong to week 24 too. Week 24 in 2022. You should add another condition to your query to remove those records from showing.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be nothing wrong. Since there is a week 24 in every year, you also get results for the year 2022.

The `week` of `datepart` has a maximum of 53 and then starts at 1 for the next year:

```
select datepart(week, '2021-06-08') -- 24

select datepart(week, '2022-01-01') -- 1

select datepart(week, '2022-06-05') -- 24
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=de7a40726c9f7fdc65128cf0d9cffc71)

If you want to limit it to one year, you have to specify it accordingly, e.g.

```
select INSTALLATION_DATE 
  from {MyTABLE} 
 where datepart(week,INSTALLATION_DATE)=24  
   and datepart(year,INSTALLATION_DATE)=2021
```

Answer (score 0):

Week 24 in 2020 lasts from Monday, 07.06.2020 to Sunday, 13.06.2020.

Week 24 in 2021 lasts from Monday, 07.06.2021 to Sunday, 13.06.2021.

Week 24 in 2022 lasts from Monday, 05.06.2022 to Sunday, 11.06.2022.

Your query

```
select INSTALLATION_DATE 
from {MyTABLE} 
where datepart(WEEK,INSTALLATION_DATE)=24
```

works as it should.

If you want to not get future dates you can add:
`AND INSTALLATION_DATE <= GETDATE()`

Instead, if you want to get only current year dates add:
`AND YEAR(INSTALLATION_DATE)=2020`